# array to create a linked-list

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list

```
typedef struct num{
    int num;
    int pre;
    struct num* next;
}Num;

Num list[10]=
{{3,4},{2,1},{6,5},{7,2},{4,3},{3,9},{5,6},{1,3},{8,4},{10,0}
};

#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int cnt;
    Num *ptr = NULL;

    Num tempTwo;
    for (cnt = 0; cnt < 10; cnt++) {
        tempTwo = list[cnt]; 
        ptr->next = &tempTwo; //Error
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    for (cnt = 0; cnt<10; cnt++) {
        printf("num: %d, pre: %d\n",ptr->num,ptr->pre);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

I want to make linked-list with array 'list' using pointer ptr.

```
Error: Bad access
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: `ptr->next = &tempTwo;` produces an error because you set `Num *ptr = NULL;` before the first loop iteration.

Comment: But Xcode makes initialize, and if I don't do that num is just 10 and pre is always 0.

Comment: You can't point to anything with a `NULL` pointer: it has no target.

Comment: Are you familiar with `malloc`?

Comment: Yes. Delete the NULL then Xcode prints result. But num is always 10 and pre is always 0.

Comment: I must make list with array. It's an assignment...

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: Oh I must make linked-list with array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct num{
    int num;
    int pre;
    struct num* next;
}Num;

Num list[10]= {
    {3,4},{2,1},{6,5},{7,2},{4,3},{3,9},{5,6},{1,3},{8,4},{10,0}
};

int main(){

    int cnt;
    Num *head, *ptr;

    list[9].next = NULL;               // marks the end of the list
    for (cnt=8; cnt>=0; cnt--)
        list[cnt].next = &list[cnt+1]; // point to next list item
    head = &list[0];                   // point to first list item

    // test
    ptr = head;
    while (ptr) {
        printf ("%d %d\n", ptr->num, ptr->pre);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
3 4
2 1
6 5
7 2
4 3
3 9
5 6
1 3
8 4
10 0
```

Comment: I didn't have to do it that way round, because the array already existed. But usually the easiest way to add an item to a simply linked list is to add it to the front, and then when you print the list it comes out in reverse order.